# "Invalid Encoding" error on backups created with WinRAR

Tags: encoding, crash, rar

I recently installed ubuntu. I have my files (windows, office, jpg, etc.) compressed in `.rar`.

My native language is spanish. I got "invalid encoding" whenever I tried to decompress. I though I managed to correct it by installing `utf8-migration-tool`.

It was all fine until... I opened one folder and it crashed. Over and over again. I tried to re-decompress and it was the same. Does anyone know how can I solve it please?

I'm a beginner with Ubuntu. I really like this OS! Thanks in advance.

Rodrigo

Answer (score 0):

How did you extract the files? RAR is a proprietary format and not included in the default install. Did you install [unrar](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unrar-free/)?

If that does not work, you could try to extract the files from terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) by executing `unrar x your_archive.rar`.

I recommend the built in ZIP tool from Windows or [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) ([link in Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/p7zip-full/)) for creating portable archives.